# Why is Spectrasonics Omnisphere polyphony so limited compared to similar virtual instruments?

Tags: vst

Could anybody please explain why Omnisphere has issues handling higher numbers of simultaneous voices (polyphony)? I would prefer answers backed by some evidence 
 or available information about the product. Perhaps a convincing technical argument would be a good answer. Thank you!

A possible answer could be a lack of optimization of the sound engine. That is what I suspect, but I have no information to back that up.

I own multiple virtual synths (software plugins) and I do not have issues with so many pops, clicks and buffer underruns as with Omnisphere. Most presets in Omnisphere have a default of around 8 voices. Increasing that in most cases results in the sound being unusable due to the aforementioned issue. My computer has an Intel i7 cpu, an SSD drive and 16 GB of RAM and as I said all my other plugins run well. I can get polyphony of over 128 voices with many of them without issues. In case it matters I have version 2.6 of Omnisphere.

Comment: The maximum polyphony is 64 anyway. And they talk of reducing it "to 16 or even 10" to reduce CPU overload, so the more complicated patches obviously use a lot more CPU power than your average virtual instrument. https://support.spectrasonics.net/manual/Omnisphere2/25/en/topic/concepts-page02